# Eisenstein Integers

Tags: soft-question, eisenstein-integers

Tag description says the tag is for questions about the Eisenstein Integers.

Apologies for the question.

I'd like to be a bit more informed about what they are related to, and what is the motivation.

Trying to single out what and why my self mostly gives me an almost sense of vertigo.

Links to resources should suffice.

Thanks.

Comment: The topic is field theory, field extensions, Galois groups, ring of integers, abstract algebra, algebraic integers, prime ideals. The simplest examples are $\mathbb{Z}[i]\cong\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2-1)$ and $\mathbb{Z}[\omega]\cong\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2+x+1)$ the Gaussian and Eisenstein integers.

Comment: Thanks. However these are not examples but restatements in the end. Question: $\mathbb{Z[\omega]}$ is primarily used for the distinguished algebraic characteristics? - Nothing about the triangular lattice as is? Where and how does the complex manifold aspect come in?

Comment: What you write is unclear. You should google the terms I wrote. $\mathbb{C}/(\mathbb{Z}+\omega \mathbb{Z}) = \mathbb{C}/\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$ is a complex torus. But $\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$ is not only an abelian group, it has also a multiplication making it a commutative ring, with fraction field $\mathbb{Q}(\omega)$. This is where algebraic number theory (with prime numbers and reduction $\bmod p$) becomes the subject, not complex analysis.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. Was trying to compress all of my questions. Thanks a lot. :). Would still very much like a concrete  recommendation on material :)

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? More to the point, what are you looking for that Wikipedia, etc. doesn't have?

Answer (score 3):

One application in differential geometry is that the torus $\mathbb C/L$ where $L$ are the Eisenstein integers happens to be extremal for the Loewner torus inequality in [systolic geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systolic_geometry).

Comment: This, is great.